# MongoDB query the field inside the array of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

```js
{
  "_id": 1,
  "posts":[
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "title": "my title",
      "content": "some post content here...",
      "comments": [
        {
          "_id": 1,
          "text": "my comment"
        },
        {
          "_id": 2,
          "text": "your_comment"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here how would I query/fetch the documents which match this text 'my comment' in the **text** field of **comments** array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this simple query for `find`:

```
{
  "posts.comments.text": "my comment"
}
```